# How to make this bar

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a resume with angular and am looking for something that can visually quantify my level of skill with certain subjects. I like this here:

[image: slider barr??]

The problem I am having is I am not sure what I need to google so I can research what I need. The closest thing I could find to this is called a slider bar. My alternative solution was also to use a rating scale, although I do not like the separated stars going this route. I would prefer a solid line like the pic.

Comment: Please show us what your expected result is, and what you've tried.

Comment: sorry couldnt figure out how to add a picture

Comment: You need to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use basic CSS to create these. You wouldn't want to implement actual slider controls anyway, since you're displaying constant values. Look into `border-radius` and relative/absolute positioning.

Comment: Fun fact @LGSon, you can use the shorthand `[ask]` in the comments and it will result in this nice link-> [ask]. I learned that trick not too long ago, thought I'd share. :)

Comment: @Narm Thanks a lot...never knew that all these years, it will save tons of writing :) ... and say Hello to your dog

Answer (score 2):

I would attempt to solve your issue with a custom directive.  Now I'm assuming you are using @angular since you didnt specify but the logic is viable for all versions.

First, set up your fake div slider template (@Component) as such:

```
<div class="skill-slider">
  <div class="skill-level" [ngClass]="{low: isLow, med: isMed, high: isHigh}">      
  </div>
</div
```

Then your css could correspond to your variables.  So you may need to create more variables:

```
    .skill-slider{
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
}

.skill-level{
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #4523EF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 3px;
}

.low{
  left: 20px
}

.med{
  left: 50px;
}

.high{
  left: 90px;
}
```

Then in your controller set the variable

```
...
isMed = true;
isLow = false;
isHigh = false;
...
```

Your corresponding class should take effect and the slider will move accordingly.  Good luck!

Here's a fiddle you can play with to get it right. https://jsfiddle.net/d1mfua3r/

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this problem: Find a good CCS framework to use (I like "Bootstrapp" when I do angular development). After that look into some examples. Here is somthing to get you close to what you need.

Make an angular *ngFor to loop through your list of topics "Public speaking", "Social Media", "Mic Dropping", "Golfing" etc. Then use this HTML in each of the ngFor items. You can use string interpolation {{}} to get the values of "golfing" by doing {{object.yourtitle}}. I'm using placeholder names since you did not post any code

here is an example of the HTML and CSS from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

HTML:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slidecontainer {
        width: 100%; /* Width of the outside container */
    }

    /* The slider itself */
    .slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;   
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    /* Mouse-over effects */
.slider:hover {
        opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
    }

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript for the slider:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

If you are using angular then you can skip the javascript of "document.getElementById" and instead access the items by the object names and values in the component.